# Example for uncorrelated, not independent , but with same distribution functions random variables

Tags: distributions, correlation, random-variable, independence

I am looking for an example of two random variables X and Y on $\Omega=\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ with the following properties:

a) X and Y have the same distribution

b) X and Y are uncorrelated

c) X and Y are dependent

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you meant "c) X and Y are _dependent_"? Because otherwise the question is a non-question: Specify _any_ marginal distribution, identical for $X$ and $Y$, and then just _declare_ that they are uncorrelated and independent.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will correct it. I meant "dependent"

Comment: This is a duplicate of a [question asked earlier](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/999880/15941) on math.SE where I gave an example in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the probability measure assigns equal probability $\frac{1}{5}$
to the five singleton events $\{-2\}, \{-1\}, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{2\}$
whose union is $\Omega = \{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$.
The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are mappings from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$,
and each of the two random variables maps the five outcomes in $\Omega$
to $\{-1,0,1\}$. The *joint* mapping is as follows.

$$\begin{align}
(X,Y)(-2)&=(0,1),\\
(X,Y)(-1)&=(1,0),\\
(X,Y)(0)&=(0,0),\\
(X,Y)(1)&=(-1,0),\\
(X,Y)(2)&=(0,-1).
\end{align}$$
Put another way, $X$ and $Y$ have *identical* marginal pmfs
$$p(-1) = p(1) = \frac15, p(0) = \frac 35.$$
It is easy to see that $E[X]=E[Y]=E[XY]=0$ and so $X$ and $Y$ are
uncorrelated. It is also easy to verify that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent
random variables.

---

Oh, you mean $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ is the *range* of $X$ and $Y$ and not
the sample space? Well, can you generalize the above idea? Hint: put
equal probability $\frac 19$ on the axis points $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$.